# BrickJax: Brick Image Replacement for Bricks.StackExchange.com

Tags: script

## Screenshot

[image: BrickJax in Action]

## About

We've put together a script that we're hoping to get added to [LEGO Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com) that will allow users to easily insert images of Bricks, with or without links, and also links to sets on various listings sites via simple tags.

The supported tags are:

- `[part:3700:4]`
  Draw a part (Technic Brick 1 x 2 with Hole) in a colour (red).
- `[partlink:3700:4]`
  Draw a part (Technic Brick 1 x 2 with Hole) in a colour (red) and link to it on Peeron.com.
- `[set:5590]`
  Link to set 5590 on Peeron.
- `[bl:5590]`
  Link to set 5590 on BrickLink.
- `[bs:5590]`
  Link to set 5590 on BrickSet.

## License

The script makes use of the jQuery replaceText script and therefore must be used in a way consistent with that plugin's dual MIT/GPLv2 license.

## Download

[install / update script](https://github.com/Zhaph/BrickJax/raw/master/BrickJax.user.js) | [Source](https://github.com/Zhaph/BrickJax) - Updated 06/07/18

## Examples

The following question and answers has some codes in comments and my answer that will show this in action:

> [Code to insert parts](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/99/56)

## Platform

The script should work under all major userscript-supporting browsers, however it's currently only been tested in Chrome with Tampermonkey and Firefox with Greasemonkey. Please file a bug if you encounter any issues.

## Contact

[Zhaph - Ben Duguid](https://stackapps.com/users/401/zhaph-ben-duguid) actively maintains this script, with the bulk of the original code developed by [Kevin Cathcart](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/184/kevin-cathcart).

You can also find us in Chat at [Bricks.SE Parts JavaScript Discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1741/bricks-se-parts-javascript-discussion)

Comment: Cool! I'm going to try this out right away.

Comment: Do you have an example question / answer I can test the script with?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison - Sorry, yep, on our meta: http://meta.bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/62/code-to-insert-parts There should be at least one in some comments, and a couple in my answer.