# Obtain JSON equivalent of a full Q&A HTML page?

Tags: support, api, questions, api-v2.2

I want to write an application for which, after some logic to select a set of questions, it would be most convenient to get the whole set of stuff at once that is normally shown on a Stack Exchange Q&A webpage (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506705/bottle-and-json)):

- the question
- its metadata (score, dates, author, etc.)
- its comments
- all answers
- all of each answer's metadata
- all of each answer's comments

How surprised was I to find nothing like that in the API!
I have looked through the [Stack Apps tour](https://stackapps.com/tour), the [FAQs](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/faq),
and of course the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

But even the most promising-looking operations come nowhere near this functionality:
[/questions/{ids}/answers](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions) and [/questions/{ids}/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-questions) do not,
[/search](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/search) and [/search/advanced](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) do not,
[/posts](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts) and [/posts/{ids}/comments](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-on-posts) do not.

What am I missing?

Or is there seriously no way to get from the API in one request what the Stack Exchange servers produce hundreds of thousands of times every day in response to a single browser-level URL request for a web page?

Of course, I could parse the HTML.
But not only does that look like trouble -- it should simply not be necessary, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is indeed a way: Just use an appropriate filter with `/questions` or `/search`.**

For example, you can get roughly the JSON equivalent of page 
[How do I get a GreaseMonkey/UserScript to interact with the Live Preview?](https://stackapps.com/q/2804)
with this query:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/2804?&site=stackapps.com&filter=!BHTP%29W3VIPP%29cNVPt8on92i1%28WJFk1

The key is to [configure the filter](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter)
not only to include the `/questions` elements you want,
but also the `/answers` elements and even the `/comments` elements.
(Or just reuse the above filter.)

If in the filter's `question` fields you have selected `answers`,
the API will apply the filter's `answer` fields to determine what answer fields
to include.
If in the filter's `answer` fields you have selected `comments`,
the API will apply the filter's `comment` fields to determine what comment fields
to include in the answer parts of the questions result of your `/questions` query.
Likewise for the question's immediate comments.

So why have I not found this during my initial search for a solution? 
(I am answering my own question here)

Two reasons:

- It is not enough, when assessing the `/questions` query type, to read 
  the page [/docs/questions-by-ids](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids)
  (or [/docs/questions](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) for that matter),
  you also need to follow the link "[question objects](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)"
  to get enlightened.
- The term "filter" for the filters is misleading.
  "transitive results structure specifiers" would be more appropriate.

My conclusion:
There is room left for improvement of the API documentation,
but the API itself is quite flexible.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Should I combine this question and answer into a new post tagged FAQ? I tend to be a reasonably attentive reader of documentation.